# "You'll need a new app to open...." localhost running Sharepoint 2016 app

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2017, sharepoint-2016

While running a SharePoint 2016 application from VS2019 (debug mode), I go to 'Site Settings', in IE 11, and click on my link.  When I do, I get this

[image]

If I click, "Allow" I get another popup stating, "**You'll need a new app to open localhost**".  I read up on this and see the page is more likely complaining about the url not being formed properly but this is the same link that this page has ever had (http://localhost//).  I don't know why this is happening.

The page is a plain aspx page with Sharepoint and AngularJS:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
     <script src="/_layouts/packages/angular.1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

     <script>
        var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

        angular.element(function () {
            document.getElementById("myFrame").src = document.location.protocol == "http:" ?
            document.location.hostname + ':8368/Pages/mypage.aspx?' + window.location.search.substr(1) :
            document.location.hostname + ':8268/Pages/mypage.aspx?' + window.location.search.substr(1);
        });


    </script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <body class="flex-container">
        <div>
            <iframe style="width:100%; height:850px" frameborder="0" id="myFrame"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</asp:Content>
```

This basically has two pages - one for http and https.  These get loaded into an iframe (for a good reason which is irrelevant). Then my content page is loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.core.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Page.css" />

<style>
    .k-button {
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
    ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
        color: gray;
        opacity: 0.7; /* Firefox */
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
        color: gray;
        opacity: 0.7; 
    }

    ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
        color: gray;
        opacity: 0.7; 
    }
    .k-textbox {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Page details

It's not getting this far but I posted it just to provide the context.  The main issue is why I get a message saying I need to have an app to run local host.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I didn't prepend '*document.location.protocol*' to the urls of my pages. It should be '*document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + ':8268/Pages/mypage.aspx?' + window.location.search.substr(1);*"